# Windows API calls memory leak detection

Tags: delphi

AFAIK, the FastMM ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutdown couldn't detect memory leaks caused by direct Windows API call, such as unfreed handle. What is the best tool/way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Memproof:
http://www.scip.be/index.php?Page=ArticlesDelphi07&Lang=EN

Comment: I use Delphi 2010. How AQTime compared to EurekaLog?

Comment: EurekaLog works like FastMM, there is no feature of WinAPI calls verifying.